# How to Get Past The Apocalypse - Quickly

Tags: dystopia

Inspired by [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167737/one-half-of-my-population-was-eliminated-how-do-i-restore-them-without-causing), it's an often used gimmick to juice interest by ending the world. It could be the machine uprising, nuclear apocalypse, zombie virus, nano disease, unbeatable army of undead, box full of bad, magic oven mitt, or something else.

Critics charge that world builders wimp out - reversing the situation as quickly as possible, once they realize their loyal fans never signed up for dystopic literature.

How do I quickly get back to a world wholesome enough for my readers to care about it the next time it's in jeopardy?

Constraints :

- Without reversing the apocalypse. Some or all of the dead might be brought back, somehow. But, this thing still happened for many (maybe most).

Comment: After a gruesome battle and some time travel (possible due to a random rat), the great oven mitt is recombined (https://images.app.goo.gl/wTcTHcuxGE77iTUNA). But the villain manages to capture it and almost do all the bad stuff again! But as he makes ready to unleash the villain gets in a scuffle just before he can moo the oven mitt and the hero steals the oven mitt's power! With a one-liner worthy of the self-centeredness of the hero he sacrifices himself and stops the villain for good, resetting most of the world to its former glory.

Comment: This is a story or even a *writing* question, rather than worldbuilding one. As such, it's a lot more suited to [writing.se] because you're asking for techniques to move the story along, rather than specific worldbuilding scenario.

Comment: Hm. Although I used words related to writing, the question is intended to be media-independent. Seems more like a world building problem to me. This isn't about foreshadowing or pacing but how to confront a world building problem many face and back away from.

Comment: I agree that it's more of a writing question, but I think many people who enjoy the apocalyptic genre are likely to see the current world, or at least particular aspects of it, as the dystopia, and be interested in how a better (or at least different) society might arise after the apocalypse.

Comment: This is framed as a writing question but imo it's on-topic because the question itself - how do I get past the apocalypse - has to do with the events of the world. The author's **purpose** for doing so has to do with writing - but the actual **subject** is fully within the scope of building the world. I'm going to VTC as "needs details or clarity" because we need to know what type of apocalypse we're dealing with, but this isn't off-topic.

Comment: @Zxyrra Well put. You're exactly right. This is a question about the capability of a world to get past an apocalypse. The OP has made that writing decision, this is worldbuilding. What aspects of a world enable overcoming an apocalypse. It's that simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the next apocalypse meaningful without undoing this one i think your best but would be time jumps. Time heals all wounds so if you are willing to make the story cross several generations this would be the way to go.

If on the other hand time is an issue the best alternative would be have the surviving population of the world integrate in to new society.

Let's say your entire story takes place in a sci-fi setting, the world went through an apocalypse and even though the main characters survived its still all shit. Leaving for an other world and finding new life there would provide something worth fighting for. You could go for a lush new world without higher intelligence or a new world with humanoids beings running around that are causing trouble for your colonists.

Alternatively (although i am personally not a fan of how it got handled in these series) you can go down the path of The Divergent/ Mazerunner series where the world seemed like it ended (Because it did for their known world) but the larger whole is still open (and vulnerable).

If this doesn't work i am afraid you are stuck with god/Magic/Time travel to fix the worlds problems.

Comment: Integrate with the new reality was also my first thought. I like the change the scene idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options I see:

### Disaster vs Apocalypse

As long as the infrastructure and culture survives, this could merely be a disaster.

Especially if infrastructure survives, here are some options :

**The disaster is happening offscreen.** Yes, that frozen army of the dead swept across most of the continent before finally being stopped at horrific losses. South of the fighting, only a little has changed : there are fewer men (most lost in the war). Homesteading into the now-abandoned land is a thing now. But life is otherwise only the smallest bit different than it was before.

**The disaster wasn't as bad as it seemed.** Think about Chernobyl, which actually looks pretty good. The animals have cancers, yes. But the world adjusted surprisingly quickly to a new normal that looks very much like the old normal.

But maybe infrastructure and culture was really blown away:

**Reminders of the disaster are just out of sight, and pushed out-of-mind.** Think Germany after the holocaust. The nuclear apocalypse happened. But this is the story of the people in Shelter 8392-A, who are pretty good (maybe not perfect) people. (similar to 'The 100', or 'Battlestar Galactica').

**Or, we're focusing the area of regard on the positive.**
The machine revolution happened (or the zombie apocalypse). And they were defeated at awful cost. But now we focus on some of the rebuilding towns that look like undisturbed subdivisions, complete with landscaping (like 'Demolition Man'). Or maybe it's a 'Mad Max' -like resource shortage, or a 'Water World' -like natural disaster, but we focus on the upbeat survivors that we can care about. Doesn't mean life is good, or that reminders don't exist, just that these people are CHOOSING to live in a better now.

### Moving Somewhere Else

Like the animals in 'Ice Age' there could be a short migration to some place the apocalypse / disaster hasn't touched. Almost no time needs to elapse as people settle in the new world.

### Moving Forward in Time

It only takes a generation (~30 years) for an atrocity to become folklore. In that same amount of time, a lot of rebuilding can be done, and the world might look much as it once was.

Answer (score 1):

#### Consider what the reader is getting attached to:

Typically, readers are attached to characters more strongly than to abstract elements of the setting.  Compare these two phrases to describe the same event: "The planet Alderaan was destroyed" and "Princess Leia watched as her home planet of Alderaan was destroyed".  The second carries more weight because it conveys the event relative to a character that the audience knows.

Extend this to your apocalyptic event: the readers will probably feel less emotional response from finding that 90% of the fictional world has been destroyed and billions of people were killed, than they would from finding out that the protagonist had to watch his small hometown be destroyed and witness his close friends and family members die.

#### An Apocalypse by Degrees:

So, the quickest and easiest way to have your Apocalypse and beat it too, is to have it happen in ways that are personal to the characters that the audience cares about.  You can have the event strike distant cities, and see the characters react to this information.  You can have this cause food shortages, or sudden flows of refugees.  The apocalypse affects the characters, but not in the harshest or most direct way.

Over time, they--and the world in general--can adapt to the new status quo.  Then, the event can repeat more severely, or more closely, and the characters will have to react in an even more extreme way to this development.

#### Example:

One day, a large asteroid breaks up in Earth's atmosphere, scattering debris along its path.  The debris has an unusual property: direct exposure to a human voice will cause it to dissolve into a tear in reality, unleashing horrific monstrosities that kill any human they find, converting the remains into further monstrosities.

The protagonist lived far from any of the incursion sites, but the calamity spread far and wide.  After a decade of fighting and fleeing, the protagonist has formed a new community with their family, friends, and other survivors they picked up along the way.  They haven't seen any monstrosities for several years, and are fully self-sufficient.

But one day, a farmer is clearing a patch of Earth to expand a field, and their pickaxe clangs off of something.  They say "What's that?", and the ground before them opens suddenly into blackness, and gibbering monstrosities begin to claw out...

The second "apocalypse" is much smaller than the first, but fits with the original one, and can have a much more meaningful impact for the audience as it now directly impacts the characters they know.  Civilization is also much more fragile at this point, so a smaller event can be even more catastrophic.

Answer (score 0):

**The original had a limited point of view.**

First, definitions:

If it's a REAL "Apocalypse", as the term is commonly used, the culture and social contracts of a society are utterly and irreparably destroyed. A new culture and social contracts must develop, which is how you get to the dystopia.

If the old culture perseveres or recovers, then the event was merely a "Cataclysmic Disaster".

It's [Chekhov's Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun): If you use the term 'apocalypse' vs. 'disaster', folks have certain expectations. The storyteller's job is to make the scale of the disaster clear to the audience regardless of the terms you choose.

Second, story:

It's quite possible that the earlier story had a limited point of view. Perhaps it took place within the disaster zone, or was influenced by an unreliable narrator.

As the larger society restores control and begins to recover the disaster area, normalcy will quickly return.

Example: "To my town, the tsunami was an apocalypse. So many friends gone. The people were different afterward - so many strange faces and rough accents, and nobody smiled anymore. It was lonely. It wasn't home anymore. The posters went up even before the bulldozers finished clearing the rubble from the street, and the loudspeaker towers appeared days before the power came back on."

Comment: It's good to know that. I wasn't aware of the distinction